# How broadcasting video on twitch?

Tags: java, video-streaming, rtmp, twitch, xuggler

Sorry for my bad english.
Help me figure out how you can broadcast video on twitch using java.

I did not leave a working example on the Internet

Can I implement my rtmp protocol?

Help please, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Twitch t = new Twitch();
Video v = new Video("video.mp4");
t.play(v);
```